# SSRS 2008 how to count values equal to the current cell?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to add a placeholder to a cell that includes a count of rows from that dataset that have that the same value.

Example:

```
| ID    |   Value   |
| 1     |   123 (3) |
| 2     |   123 (3) |
| 3     |   456 (2) |
| 4     |   123 (3) |
| 5     |   456 (3) |
| 6     |   789 (1) |
```

This is what I have so far, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
Fields!cpt4_code.Value
```

Instead of it indicating how many times that value occurs, it simply count the number of rows return in that dataset.

Is this even possible with one dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You should use LookupSet for this:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!fieldOne.Value, Fields!fieldOne.Value, Fields!fieldOne.Value, "DataSetNameHere").Length
```

LookupSet returns an array, hence the ".Length" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Think this kinda thing is what you need

> =Sum(IIF(Fields!field name.value,1,0),"DatasetNameHere")

Comment: That will return the row count, but not the number of rows that the target column equals the value of the current cell.  So if ID 1 is "123" and there are 2 other values of "123" in that column, in the dataset, then it should display "(3)" next to that value.